# How to highlight one BarDataSet entry in a CombinedChart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I have a combined chart consisting of one bar chart and one line chart. When I open the chart activity, I would like to have the entry at x position 3.0f, for only the bar chart, highlighted. When I call `mCombinedChart.highlight(3.0f, int dataSetIndex, false)`, it gives me a null pointer exception, regardless of what `int` I have as the data set index. How could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a highlight object: `Highlight high = new Highlight(float x, int dataSetIndex);`
2. **Call the set data index method:** `high.setDataIndex(int dataIndex);`
3. `mCombinedChart.highlightValue(high, false)`

Use the setDataIndex method to choose which data object of your combined chart you want to use, and use the dataSetIndex value as the index of the data set of your selected data object.